# Why are there two tags about the "show" and "tell" advice?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I came across a [question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/56215/how-do-i-show-that-my-character-is-intelligent) tagged both [show-dont-tell](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-dont-tell) and [showing-telling](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing-telling). There is a tag wiki for the second but not the first. It says:

- This tag should be used for questions about the [technique] of "Show, don't tell!" The goal of this technique is to allow the reader to experience the story through senses and feelings instead of only listening to the author explaining something.

Should these not be synonyms? I don't have the rep to do that myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right: these tags are identical, and we don't need both of them.

I've made [show-dont-tell](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-dont-tell) a synonym of [showing-telling](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing-telling), and the two questions with the [show-dont-tell](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-dont-tell) tag have been automatically retagged to use [showing-telling](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing-telling) instead.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention - and sorry for not noticing until now!